# How to check in PHP if a checkbox is checked or not before posting/submitting?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to check if a checkbox has been selected so that if it is, I can then display another textbox, however I've tried the below code to try and check if the checkbox is checked or not but keep getting errors. I need to check before the form is submitted/posted as the text field that shows after needs submitting with the form.

HTML + PHP:

```
<div class="form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" name = "job_mileage_check" class="form-check-input" id="job_mileage">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="job_mileage">Mileage?</label>
</div>
<?php
    $check_value = isset(['job_mileage_check']) ? 1 : 0;
?>
```

All/Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can not check that, before any data was sent back to the server - that is where PHP executes. If you do not want to submit the full form at this point - then make an AJAX request in the background.

Comment: If you want to show a checkbox, if another is checked you need to try a Front-End-Language, for example javascript.

Comment: _“I need to check before the form is submitted/posted as the text field that shows after needs submitting with the form.”_ - that doesn’t mean that you have to perform that check using PHP on the server side though. This would rather be a use case to perform that check, and then depending on the result, show/enable the additional text field or not, using JavaScript.

Comment: `PHP` is unnecessary for what you're asking. You need to create a page in `HTML` that has `JavaScript` that checks for the checkbox and then toggles whatever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this in front but with checkbox

Form

```
<div id='radios'>
 <div class="form-check">
  <input type="radio" id="inputRadio1" value="data1">
  <label class="form-check-label">myText1</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-check">
  <input type="radio" id="inputRadio2" value="data2">
  <label class="form-check-label">myText2</label>
 </div>
```

JS

```
const inputRadio1 = document.getElementById('radioinputRadio1');
const inputRadio2 = document.getElementById('radioinputRadio2');
const btnSubmit = document.getElementById('btnSubmit');

btnSubmit.addEventListener('click', e => {
 if (!inputRadio1.checked && !inputRadio2.checked) {
  // error 
  // ...
  e.preventDefault();  
 } 
});
```